# Android IllegalStateException while finishing Activity

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, activity-finish

I got this exception

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not be called to deliver a result"
```

And didn't immediately understand why. Below is my answer to why this happened, maybe this helps someone.

Comment: Well, this has helped me and it looks as if it has helped other as well. So maybe not so off-topic right?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had called finishAffinity() after having set a result code. Android was complaining that it will never be able to deliver the result when calling finishAffinity().

Solution: either don't set the result before calling finishAffinity(), or set the result again before calling finishAffinity() but this time with Activity.RESULT_CANCELED as the result code:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: Not sure if the API changed, but I believe this is supposed to call `setResultCode()` instead of `setResult()`.

Comment: I'm still seeing setResult() in the docs...?
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)

Comment: @DaveLeeds there is no "setResultCode()" for Activities, only BroadcastReceivers